# Set-ItemProperty ignores trailing .

Tags: registry, powershell-v5.1

Using Powershell 5.1, I am trying to create a registry value under:
`HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Classes\.`
(Note trailing period)

Unfortunately [Set-ItemProperty](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/set-itemproperty?view=powershell-5.1) appears to ignore the trailing . and creates the value under:
`HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Classes`
instead.

I'm running Powershell ISE as admin, and tested all sorts of quotes, Path & LiteralPath, back-tick escape and trailing / to no avail.

I've tried the following under a different key in case there is anything weird with Classes...

```
$PSVersionTable.PSVersion

New-Item -Path 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\aTest\.' -ItemType RegistryKey -Force -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue > $null
New-Item -Path 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\aTest\`.' -ItemType RegistryKey -Force -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue > $null

Set-ItemProperty -LiteralPath HKLM:\SOFTWARE\aTest\.   -Name 'Test01' -Value 'emptyFile' -Verbose;
Set-ItemProperty -LiteralPath 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\aTest\.' -Name 'Test02' -Value 'emptyFile' -Verbose;
Set-ItemProperty -LiteralPath "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\aTest\." -Name 'Test03' -Value 'emptyFile' -Verbose;

Set-ItemProperty -Path HKLM:\SOFTWARE\aTest\.   -Name 'Test04' -Value 'emptyFile' -Verbose;
Set-ItemProperty -Path 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\aTest\.' -Name 'Test05' -Value 'emptyFile' -Verbose;
Set-ItemProperty -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\aTest\." -Name 'Test06' -Value 'emptyFile' -Verbose;

Set-ItemProperty -LiteralPath HKLM:\SOFTWARE\aTest\`.   -Name 'Test07' -Value 'emptyFile' -Verbose;
Set-ItemProperty -LiteralPath 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\aTest\`.' -Name 'Test08' -Value 'emptyFile' -Verbose;
Set-ItemProperty -LiteralPath "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\aTest\`." -Name 'Test09' -Value 'emptyFile' -Verbose;

Set-ItemProperty -Path HKLM:\SOFTWARE\aTest\`.   -Name 'Test10' -Value 'emptyFile' -Verbose;
Set-ItemProperty -Path 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\aTest\`.' -Name 'Test11' -Value 'emptyFile' -Verbose;
Set-ItemProperty -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\aTest\`." -Name 'Test12' -Value 'emptyFile' -Verbose;

Set-ItemProperty -LiteralPath HKLM:\SOFTWARE\aTest\.\   -Name 'Test13' -Value 'emptyFile' -Verbose;
Set-ItemProperty -LiteralPath 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\aTest\.\' -Name 'Test14' -Value 'emptyFile' -Verbose;
Set-ItemProperty -LiteralPath "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\aTest\.\" -Name 'Test15' -Value 'emptyFile' -Verbose;

Set-ItemProperty -Path HKLM:\SOFTWARE\aTest\.\   -Name 'Test16' -Value 'emptyFile' -Verbose;
Set-ItemProperty -Path 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\aTest\.\' -Name 'Test17' -Value 'emptyFile' -Verbose;
Set-ItemProperty -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\aTest\.\" -Name 'Test18' -Value 'emptyFile' -Verbose;
```

but the output shows it ignores the . unless literally escaped (when it creates a key with the back-tick in it...

```
Major  Minor  Build  Revision
-----  -----  -----  --------
5      1      17134  228
VERBOSE: Performing the operation "Set Property" on target "Item: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\aTest Property: Test01".
VERBOSE: Performing the operation "Set Property" on target "Item: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\aTest Property: Test02".
VERBOSE: Performing the operation "Set Property" on target "Item: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\aTest Property: Test03".
VERBOSE: Performing the operation "Set Property" on target "Item: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\aTest Property: Test04".
VERBOSE: Performing the operation "Set Property" on target "Item: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\aTest Property: Test05".
VERBOSE: Performing the operation "Set Property" on target "Item: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\aTest Property: Test06".
VERBOSE: Performing the operation "Set Property" on target "Item: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\aTest Property: Test07".
VERBOSE: Performing the operation "Set Property" on target "Item: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\aTest\`. Property: Test08".
VERBOSE: Performing the operation "Set Property" on target "Item: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\aTest Property: Test09".
VERBOSE: Performing the operation "Set Property" on target "Item: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\aTest Property: Test10".
VERBOSE: Performing the operation "Set Property" on target "Item: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\aTest\`. Property: Test11".
VERBOSE: Performing the operation "Set Property" on target "Item: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\aTest Property: Test12".
VERBOSE: Performing the operation "Set Property" on target "Item: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\aTest\ Property: Test13".
VERBOSE: Performing the operation "Set Property" on target "Item: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\aTest\ Property: Test14".
VERBOSE: Performing the operation "Set Property" on target "Item: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\aTest\ Property: Test15".
VERBOSE: Performing the operation "Set Property" on target "Item: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\aTest\ Property: Test16".
VERBOSE: Performing the operation "Set Property" on target "Item: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\aTest\ Property: Test17".
VERBOSE: Performing the operation "Set Property" on target "Item: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\aTest\ Property: Test18".
```

Please what am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Think about the following examples:

```
PS D:\PShell> New-Item -Path 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Test\.' -ItemType RegistryKey -WhatIf
What if: Performing the operation "New Item" 
         on target "Item: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Test".

PS D:\PShell> New-Item -Path 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Test\..' -ItemType RegistryKey -WhatIf
What if: Performing the operation "New Item" 
         on target "Item: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE".

PS D:\PShell> (Resolve-Path -LiteralPath 'HKLM:\Software\Test\.').Path
HKLM:\Software\Test

PS D:\PShell> (Resolve-Path -LiteralPath 'HKLM:\Software\Test\..').Path
HKLM:\Software
```

Apparently, Powershell's `Registry` provider takes an alone period (and doubled period as well) used as a *key path component* by analogy to suitable `FileSystem`'s *directory component* as described in [Naming Conventions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/fileio/naming-a-file#naming-conventions):

> - Use a period as a directory component in a path to represent the current directory, for example `".\temp.txt"`. For more information,
>     see [Paths](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/fileio/naming-a-file#fully-qualified-vs-relative-paths).
> - Use two consecutive periods (**`..`**) as a directory component in a path to represent the parent of the current directory, for example
>     `"..\temp.txt"`. For more information, see [Paths](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/fileio/naming-a-file#fully-qualified-vs-relative-paths).

However, [`reg.exe` allows to create, read, set or delete registry keys and values](https://ss64.com/nt/reg.html) including `.` and `..` keys, see the following examples:

```
==> reg query "HKCU\Software\Test\."

HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Test\.
    value_inside_PeriodKey    REG_SZ


==> reg add "HKCU\Software\Test\.."
The operation completed successfully.

==> reg query "HKCU\Software\Test"

HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Test
    SomeTestString    REG_SZ    Test String

HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Test\.
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Test\..
```

Please note use of `HKCU` instead of `HKLM` in the latter examples for obvious reasons (security).